# Combining columns horizontally with an arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I need to join columns with a formula (not a script) in Google Sheets in a different way than others I've found--here is my original data, supposing that the Avengers train by playing racquetball:

```
Full Name   North Court   Middle Court   South Court   Reserved Court 
---------   -----------   ------------   -----------   --------------
Ironman     Tues 4:00PM                                North Court
Hulk                      Tues 5:00PM                  Middle Court
Thor                                     Tues 5:00PM   South Court
Hawkeye                   Tues 6:00PM                  Middle Court
Antman                                   Tues 4:00PM   South Court
Spiderman                 Wed  5:00PM                  Middle Court
Captain Am  Wed  5:00PM                                North Court
```

I need to combine this data horizontally as follows:

```
Full Name   Reserved Time   Reserved Court 
---------   -------------   --------------
Ironman     Tues 4:00PM     North Court
Hulk        Tues 5:00PM     Middle Court
Thor        Tues 5:00PM     South Court
Hawkeye     Tues 6:00PM     Middle Court
Antman      Tues 4:00PM     South Court
Spiderman   Wed  5:00PM     Middle Court
Captain Am  Wed  5:00PM     North Court
```

I can achieve this on one row with the following formula:

```
=split(join(";",'Form Responses'!C2:G2),";")
```

However, I can't figure out how to make this work with an arrayformula or filter. I can't use a copydown--I need one formula/function in one cell like an arrayformula to display data in columns A through E on Sheet1 into columns A through C on Sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns you have are C-G, entering

```
=arrayformula({C2:C, D2:D & E2:E & F2:F, G2:G})
```

in the cell H2 will have the desired effect. The arrayformula indicates that in every row, one should have three entries: one from C, one is concatenation of D,E,F,  and the last from G.

Comment: Ah, thank you, @sandwich! I knew it shouldn't be as hard as I was trying to make it--nice solution!

Comment: Question @sandwich: the # of submissions will vary, so I can't put C2:C9, for example. What is the best method of getting only non-blank cells?

I thought about using an if(not(isblank(...))) around each, but that is cumbersome and I'm guessing I'm making that harder than it should be as well...plus, I'm not even sure that would work.

Comment: Replace C2:C with `filter(C2:C, len(C2:C))` to keep only the rows with nonblank entries. For consistency, the other columns must be filtered by the same criterion: `filter(D2:D, len(C2:C))` etc.

Comment: Never mind, @sandwich -- I wrapped your arrayformula in a filter as the range and for the condition, I included my timestamp in column A in this statement: datevalue(A2:A)=datevalue(now()). So, now it just pulls the current day's reservations and nothing more. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I should have refreshed my page before posting--thanks for the len solution, that will come in handy too  *added to mental toolbox

Comment: Hi again @sandwich. Could you explain why Len() works with filter to narrow down results to just the non-blank cells?

Comment: When I look at documentation on it, there is nothing to indicate that it can work this way. It only talks about using it to get the "length" of a text string and nothing about getting the number of non-blank cells in a range...this seems completely different and not at all related to returning the length of a string. Plus, it works differently than it does with a text string. If you put LEN("google docs"), it returns 11, so it doesn't skip blanks, but somehow, it knows to skip blanks when it is "counting" cells in a range?

Comment: It doesn't even seem to be counting the cells in the range--it seems like you are saying, "filter C2:C where length > 0", but there's no indication that you are giving Filter  enough information to do that... it looks like you are just saying, "filter C2:C by the length of each cell in C2:C", so it would order them by their respective lengths *mind blown